# Importing mysqlnd database to MySQL server

Tags: import, mysql-5.1

Importing a mysqlnd (5.0.12) database to MySQL server (5.1.66) causes error? Currently we are performing this task and encountering errors (like below):

> ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'xx-xxx-xxx-xxx' doesn't exist
>
> ERROR 1273 (HY000): Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
>
> ERROR 1115 (42000): Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problems may be that the `utf8mb4` character set has been added in [Mysql 5.5.3](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.5/en/news-5-5-3.html).

You need to upgrade MySQL server or change your data to working with `utf` without mb4. [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-upgrading.html) you can find some tips how to do it

Comment: but there is no mention of 5.5.3 version in my question. the source and target db versions are different from 5.5.3

Comment: if in source file this collation - You wrong about source version :-) or it was error when export (not sure how You do the export)

Comment: mysqlnd is a client library. Character set support is primarily a server feature. You have to check which server you used. MySQL 5.1 also is a very old version which is out of support or more than a year. 5.7 is current.

Answer (score 0):

in additional to the answer about support utf8mb4 from MySQL 5.5,

the problem with collation You can resolve by edit(replace) all utf8mb4 to other utf collation. If file huge, You can use sed command for change string without open the file -

```
sed -i -- 's/utf8mb4/utf/g' file.sql
```

for ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'xx-xxx-xxx-xxx' doesn't exist - not all sql dump include create table instructions, best choice check the text of script, again if file huge - use

```
cat file.sql | grep -E 'xx-xxx-xxx-xxx' | grep -E 'CREATE'
```

for check is it include in script or not